# Python's check_output method doesn't return output sometimes

Tags: python, scripting, multiprocessing

I have a Python script which is supposed to run a large number of other scripts, each located within a subdirectory of the script's working directory. Each of these other scripts is supposed to connect to a game client and run an AI for that game. To make this run, I had to run each script over two separate threads (one for each player). The problem I'm having is that sometimes the scripts' output isn't captured. My run-code looks like this:

```
def run(command, name, count):
    chdir(name)
    output = check_output(" ".join(command), stderr = STDOUT, shell = True).split('\r')
    chdir('..')
    with open("results_" + str(count) + ".txt", "w") as f:
        for line in output:
            f.write(line)
```

The strange part is that it does manage to capture longer streams, but the short ones go unnoticed. How can I change my code to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:** I don't think it's a buffering issue because `check_output("ls ..", shell = True).split('\n')[:-1]` returns the expected result and that command should take much less time than the scripts I'm trying to run.

**UPDATE 2:** I have discovered that output is being cut for the longer runs. It turns out that the end of output is being missed for all processes that I run for some reason. This also explains why the shorter runs don't produce any output at all.